# Postgres service doesnot start

Tags: postgresql

I have issue with postgres. It stops due to change in `pg_hba.conf` file

Actually my postgres was not connect with PHP

So I change in method in `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` file:

```
TYPE     DATABASE           USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host       all              all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
```

In order to solve my connection error i change the method ident to trust and postgresql servicer stops

I rollback my changes even it not started.

The error is:

> LOG: could not open configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf": Permission denied

Comment: PostgreSQL version? What's the error message from the PostgreSQL log files when you try to start it?

Comment: Please add the error from the log.

Comment: PostgreSQL version is 9.4

Comment: When I start service with /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.4 start, It shows failed

Comment: How to check error log. I am using cent-os

Comment: Log
< 2015-05-19 17:11:14.528 IST >LOG:  could not open configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf": Permission denied
< 2015-05-19 17:11:14.528 IST >FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
< 2015-05-19 17:26:48.114 IST >LOG:  could not open configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf": Permission denied
< 2015-05-19 17:26:48.114 IST >FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
< 2015-05-19 17:43:45.591 IST >LOG:  could not open configuration file "/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/pg_hba.conf": Permission denied

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that postgresql is running with postgres user, as in a standard configuration.

From terminal, as root:

```
ls -l /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf
```

And verify the owner. If the owner is not postgres:

```
chown postgres:postgres pg_hba.conf
```

And be sure it has permission to read and write:

```
chmod u+rwx pg_hba.conf
```

Comment: ThankX to reply, I always login with postgres user so user is postgres and I change the pg_hba.conf file permission even it is not started

Comment: Is currently postgresql running with postgres user? How did you edit configuration file? (gedit, vi, ecc...)

Comment: I change method ident to trust  and it stops then I rollback the change but not started then

Comment: Problem is gedit if it is on a remote machine (it rewrites the file, messing up permissions). Just login via shell and verify permission. I'm pretty sure problem is there.

Comment: How to do that dear plz let me know

Comment: and my postgres is installed on VM

Comment: Just connect to your virtual machine via ssh and tun the commands in the answer. It must fix the problem.

Comment: I just login in VM with ssh root@IP  now plz tell me which permission I should give to the pg_hba.conf file

Comment: chown postgres:postgres pg_hba.conf

Comment: Glad to help, please approve the answer :-)